# Bundling an Electron App with Angular 4 and PouchDB

Tags: angularjs, npm, electron, pouchdb, electron-packager

I have built an Electron application with Angular 4 and PouchDB.  Everything works fine when I `npm run start` the application.

However, when I bundle the application to an executable and run it, PouchDB is not working.  How can I make PouchDB work with Electron and Angular 4 when I bundle the application to an executable?

I'm using a Mac.

Here are the "scripts" from my package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "npm run build.ng && npm run build.tasks && npm run build.electron && concurrently \"npm run start.server\" \"npm run start.electron\"",
    "start.server": "pouchdb-server -d ./.db",
    "start.watch": "npm run build.ng.watch",
    "start.electron": "electron dist/electron-app.js",
    "watch": "npm run build.tasks && npm run build.electron && npm run build.watch && npm run start.electron",
    "build": "ng build --base-href . && npm run build.electron",
    "build.prod": "ng build --prod --base-href . && npm run build.electron",
    "build.ng": "ng build --base-href .",
    "build.ng.watch": "ng build --base-href . --watch",
    "build.electron": "gulp build.electron",
    "build.tasks": "gulp build.tasks",
    "build.watch": "gulp build.default",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "bundle.clean": "gulp bundle.clean",
    "bundle.prepare": "npm run bundle.prepare.npm && npm run bundle.clean",
    "bundle.prepare.npm": "gulp build.npm.copy",
    "bundle.mac": "npm run bundle.prepare && electron-packager dist/ myapp --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --overwrite --out=bundles --prune=true",
    "bundle.windows": "npm run bundle.prepare && electron-packager dist/ myapp --platform=win32 --overwrite --out=bundles --prune=true",
    "bundle.linux": "npm run bundle.prepare && electron-packager dist/ myapp --platform=linux --overwrite --out=bundles --prune=true",
    "electron-packager": "electron-packager"
  }
```

To bundle the Electron app for the mac, I run the command `npm run bundle.mac`

Comment: What is meant by `... PouchDB is not working ..`? What error messages are thrown?

Comment: It looks like you have a pouchdb-server which would run on the node side, not just pouchdb which could be run on either node or chrome side. You could probably use express-pouchdb https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb-server#express-pouchdb and then follow separate directions for setting up an express app in electron.